# ValueError:setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

When I am trying to run this piece of the code i am getting following exceptions. I have tried a lot of things. I know I am trying to assign a sequence to numpy array single value.

```
  grid = np.zeros((401, 401))
        for timestamps,poly in sorted(left_camera.iteritems()):
            polygonal = left_camera[timestamps]
            for i in range(0,len(polygonal)):
                if len(polygonal)>0:
                    row = np.int32(polygonal[i][0] * -10 + 200)
                    coloumn = np.int32(polygonal[i][1] * -10 + 200)
                    grid[row,coloumn] = np.array([255,0,0])
        cv2.imshow("image_name", grid)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

exception i am getting here:

```
grid[row,coloumn] = np.array([255,0,0])
```

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Here left_camera is my dict value with time stamps and some polygon is a list.

any solution will be much appreciated. I am new to this .

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you please paste the full TraceBack ?

Comment: sure ..  
  ret = component.ProcessData()
  File "D:\Depthmap_codes\DethMapTest-master_18_may\DethMapTest\sense\sfm\common\load_camera_points.py", line 108, in ProcessData
    grid[row,coloumn] = np.array([255,0,0])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: grid[row,coloumn] = np.array([255,0,0]) here , i am getting error

Answer (score 0):

The error points that `np.array([255,0,0])` cannot fit in the matrix as it is not an expected value to be inserted in the matrix of shape `(401, 401)`. When you create the `matrix = np.zeros((401, 401))`, it creates a matrix with height = 401 and width = 401. Since it has no third dimension, you can only substitute a single integer in this matrix as:

```
grid = np.zeros((401, 401))
grid[10, 10] = 20      # Works perfectly fine
grid[10, 10] = np.array([10, 20, 20])   # Raises Error
```

To fix this issue, you need to pass the third dimension while creating the matrix as:

```
grid = np.zeros((401, 401, 3))
grid[10, 10] = np.array([10, 20, 20])   # Works perfectly fine
```

Comment: yay it's work fine, but suppose if we have np.array((401,401)) and and we are trying to assign value as grid[10, 10] = np.array([10, 20]) will it works?

Comment: Nopes it wont, because when you define `np.array((401, 401))` and hadn't passed the third dimension then it implicitly takes `1` as the length of third dimension, so now whenever you try to substitute a value whose length is greater than `1` it will raise error, so `grid[10, 10] = np.array([10, 20])` won't work either.